# Does a background image size include the border?

Tags: css, background-image

When setting a background-image for a `<div>` element is the required image size effected by the border?

I'm working on an retina iPhone project with a  element that is 100% width. My background image is 640px wide and I'm using background-size to get it to display nicely on the retina display.

If I use a border on my `<div>` will i need to reduce the size of my image to get a 'perfect' display?

e.g.

```
320px(div) - 4px(2px border left and right) = 316px
```

So my image should be 632px (2x316) to get a 1:2 'perfect' pixel ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Background images display within the constraints of the border — that is to say the border is not included in the space that the background displays over (it will display over padding, though).

It may be helpful to your particular case to use `background-size: cover` ([MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-size))?

Comment: You can actually control this with the `background-origin` property. For example, if you set it to `border-box`, the size and position will take the borders into account. (This also influences the effect of `background-size: cover`.) The initial value is `padding-box`, which corresponds to your description.